# Does a playlist of songs or movies mixed together contain enough random enough for OTP key material?

Tags: entropy, randomness, one-time-pad

Ok hypothetical scenario. Lets say I want to generate a lot of key material quickly for a one-time pad. This key material will be divided up and used for many different messages in the future.

1. I select 50-100+ songs out of a custom playlist of all my music. The music has been converted to basic Waveform Audio File Format (.wav). The music could be a mix of rock, pop, classical, techno etc just whatever I selected.
2. I extract every song's **raw music data** out into one big file and remove null bytes. Now I have a single big file with all of the song data in it.
3. I randomize all of the song data so all the song data is blended together into an unintelligible sequence of bits. The user can provide some input using their mouse/keyboard which will provide some entropy into the randomizing function.
4. I loop through all the data in the file, taking every ~7th byte (or bit) and put it into another file which is now my new key material. This step could be altered so the user can provide a variable sample rate, e.g. they can change it to every 10th byte or 100th byte.

Now... is that file of key material sufficiently random for one-time pad use?

What about if I changed out music songs and use 10+ full length movies or TV shows instead?

Comment: The question in the title (is there enough entropy for a key?) does not match, at all, the first question in the body (can the output be used as OTP?); to the second I'd give a relatively clear _no_: if "extract every song's music data" was to 16-bit PCM format, then the MSByte of every sample is extremely biased.

Comment: Please do not deface your question - this is considered vandalism, just like when you did this editing someone else's post. If you want this question to be not anymore associated with your name, you can flag it ... the community managers (or maybe we moderators, but I'm not sure) can do this. We could also delete the question, but I think it is a fine question which is on-topic here, and has a good answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The bits are not independent from each other, at least within an individual song, so the pad is not truly random, thus this is not a one-time-pad. Perhaps a hash-based approach would fix this, but...

... there are a limited number of songs available, a simple attack would then be to enumerate every song (in the same format you describe) and try to decrypt a portion of the ciphertext (e.g. try bits 0 to 10, then try bits 1 to 11, etc... until you get something meaningful). Therefore the ciphertext can be broken by brute force, it is then not a one-time-pad by definition.

You'll notice your initial permutation had no effect on the efficiency of this attack. But even if it did, you must use some source of randomness to shuffle your song list, right? If you used a PRNG, someone could break that, and deduce the permutation you used. That's another dangerous "moving part". And if you had a true randomness source, then *why not use it to create the pad in the first place*?

Also, presumably you don't want to destroy your music after you've made it into a "one-time-pad", so your pad would also exist in its more explicit form on your hard drive -> big security risk (it considerably simplifies the attack above, as we now know exactly which songs to try to decrypt the ciphertext with).

Bits are bits, and entropy is entropy. It doesn't matter whether the data represents music or TV shows - those are human concepts whereas theoretical cryptography is intrinsically an abstract science.

Comment: You couldn't brute force it without many super computers? First the attacker has to know the key source was made from music and movies in the first place. How are they going to know that? Then the attacker has to know which music and movies were selected at random by the user. There's literally over 620 million songs in existence and over 2.3 million tv/movies titles. Then he has to know the exact combination of those songs/tv/movies that were used to generate the key. Then be able to know the media encoding used for the music/tv/movie and account for all possible combinations of that.

Comment: Then they've still got to keep trying bits of the ciphertext till they find something meaningful. Even if something 'decrypts' to something meaningful e.g. they get the word 'bob' out, how do they know they got the right key? It could've been a lucky guess. The correct decryption could easily be 'cat'. Surely with all the varying scenes in movies, trees moving in wind, clouds, actors, vehicles, motion, many different landscapes. When the data compiles down to a different coloured pixel which could be translated to a unique byte of data, surely there'd be enough random information there.

Comment: Also destroying the music/movies after creation of the pad wouldn't be necessary. Because who is to know which combination of movies and music you used to generate it in the first place. It's just a subset of a collection on a hard drive. Sure if the government seizes the computer they'd have a working base of media files to start with. It'll still take them many years on a supercomputer to figure out the individual media files used to make the key. By that point they might've just found the key itself anyway if it was left on the computer. All bets are off if they've got physical access.

Comment: @zuallauz 620 million is *nothing* in cryptography. And as I highlighted in my answer, the *order* of your song combination is irrelevant, as they are being concatenated - I can try and figure the position of each one, one after the other. I agree it wouldn't be *easy* (in human terms) but it is **not** a one-time-pad. It's just an overly complex and fragile cryptosystem (really hard to analyze, too). As for your second point, the content of songs are not random (as much as you would like them to be), so you cannot apply the equiprobable plaintext argument.

Comment: @zuallauz: Please have a look at [Kerkhoffs's principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerckhoffs's_principle) for the assumption that the attacker knows the algorithm.

Comment: I changed step 3. Once all the tv/movie data is joined together, what about randomizing all of the data? The user can provide some input using their mouse/keyboard which will provide some entropy into the randomizing function. Then in step 4 the sampling rate could be user variable too, i.e. it pulls out the 7th byte, then the 3rd byte after that, then the 5th byte after that. Pretty much you'd have an unknown selection of tv/movie data, which is then randomized, then sampled at an unknown rate. 1000 MB of data might only produce 200MB of key data which would be plenty for sending messages.

Comment: @zuallauz Then at this point, explain why not just use the entropy generated by the user to directly create the pad, instead of going through "tv/movie data"?

Comment: The thing about 620 million songs might be nothing in cryptogrophy, but remember in WAV format, that might be 45MB on average per song. This is about 26 Petabytes of information or 2.9 x 10^16 bytes of information if my maths is correct. Also if we combine in TV shows/movies at 1200MB per episode/movie in 720P/XviD format then there's over 28 PB of information. Somewhere in there the OTP key is made up of this 28PB of information, in some random order. Who has the resources to find the original OTP key from this information and the ciphertext they intercepted?

Comment: If the whole entropy is generated by the user, e.g. by moving my mouse around, tapping on the keyboard, pulling in data from /dev/random and even plugging in a random number generator dongle, how long would it take to make 200MB of usable random key material? My idea is, there's already a lot of data just sitting on a person's hard drive in the form of entertainment data which is going to be pretty unique already depending on a user's taste in music etc, why not randomize and sample that, then you can generate a lot of key material very quickly.

Comment: @zuallauz "If the whole entropy is generated by the user, e.g. by moving my mouse around, tapping on the keyboard, pulling in data from /dev/random and even plugging in a random number generator dongle, how long would it take to make 200MB of usable random key material?" A very long time, but that is the price of unconditional security. Using existing data *cannot* **by definition** be considered an appropriate source of entropy (and especially not for a one-time-pad), **no matter how ludicrously large this existing data is**. **It is the very definition of entropy.**

Comment: @zuallauz If your key is not cryptographically random, it is *not a one-time pad*. By definition. Full stop. Additionally, your PCM files will likely contain plenty of sequences of null bytes, which will leave segments of your data completely and obviously unencrypted (which will leak further information about the structure of the keys themselves). You are *infinitely* better off using less, but cryptographically random, key material and well-established symmetric encryption ciphers than using *weak* key material with a one-time pad.

Comment: Thanks @Stephen. Looking at the [WAV format](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/courses/422/projects/WaveFormat/), it looks like it won't be particularly useful unless the file is parsed and I only retain the "data subchunk" (orange colour from the diagram) which is the raw sound data as that's going to be more random. Then we'd have to strip out the null bytes too. TV and movie data may be better.

Comment: I think there seems to be a bit of a purist attitude towards how random the key material needs to be for these OTPs. If it takes a very long time to generate perfect randomness with a proper random number generator then the entire OTP scheme is not very usable. I think after steps 3 & 4 and the random song/tv/movie data is randomized and sampled, if the key data is unpredictable enough for even many supercomputers to determine the next byte in the key sequence and subsequently decrypt the message then surely that's good enough for practical use.

Comment: @zuallauz No, but you're missing the point. The OTP *is* impractical, that's why cryptography still exists. And it's not a "purist attitude" - it's been proven mathematically that the only way for the OTP to retain its security properties is if the key is fully random, which is hard to achieve. If it's not, all bets are off and you may as well be using AES. Your scheme is what we would call a *stream cipher* (albeit a very inefficient and long-winded one, which makes real life use unlikely, and thus, its security is irrelevant because it's so complicated nobody will analyze it)

Comment: @zuallauz It's nothing against you personally, really, but simple, practical cryptography that can be readily studied and analyzed has proven over the years to be so much better than complex, convoluted and unconventional algorithms like this one. Your scheme is not what I would call practical in any way. In fact, it's even more impractical than the OTP, *without* the security proof. Do you see my point?